# C# How to subscribe to a UserControl event / UserControl has no instance name

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I created a UserControl that displays data from a mySQL database(TaskSubject,Date,time).

This UserControl will be created multiple times, based on the amount of tasks.

I am creating the UserControl like this:

```
        taskSubjectPanel.Controls.Clear();
        DataTable taskdata = new DataTable();
        sql.Connect("JonasW");
        taskdata = sql.GetTasks(username);
        sql.Disconnect();

        if(taskdata.Rows.Count>0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < taskdata.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                taskSubjectPanel.Controls.Add(new TaskSubject(taskdata.Rows[i][0].ToString(),
                                                              taskdata.Rows[i][1].ToString(),
                                                              taskdata.Rows[i][2].ToString(),
                                                              taskdata.Rows[i][3].ToString(),
                                                              taskdata.Rows[i][4].ToString(),
                                                              taskdata.Rows[i][5].ToString(),
                                                              taskdata.Rows[i][6].ToString()));
            }
        }
        taskSubjectPanel.Refresh();
```

It gets added to a flowlayoutpanel.
I created a public event and a public datatable i want to have acces to when UserControl gets Clicked:

```
        public event EventHandler TaskSubjectClick;
        public DataTable taskdata;
```

Thats where the public event gets triggered:

```
        private void RedirectMouseClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           sql.Connect("JonasW");
           taskdata = sql.GetTaskData(absenderSQL, empfaengerSQL, subjectText.Text, 
           messageSQL, 
           dateText.Text, timeText.Text, finishedSQL);
           sql.Disconnect();
           this.TaskSubjectClick(this, e);
        }
```

Because it has no name, how do i acces the event and datatable ?.

Comment: Break your code up into two parts and actually assign your instance of `TaskSubject` to a local variable so that you can wire up its event as well as add it to the FlowLayoutPanel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a custom event:

```
public delegate void TaskSubjectClick(DataTable taskdata);/*<- Put all data you want to pass here*/
public event TaskSubjectClick TaskSubjectClickEvent;
```

To call the event you have to use invoke:

```
TaskSubjectClickEvent.Invoke(yourdatatable); //Invoke the event and add your data you want to pass
```

In your Mainform you have to add the event as following:

```
yourUserControl.TaskSubjectClickEvent += MainForm_TaskSubjectClickEvent;
```